# How to Integrate instamojo marketplace api using PHP cURL

Tags: payment-gateway, php-curl, instamojo

I have to integrate your Marketplace API's using simple PHP cURL.
And I am using the test Sandbox link i.e. https://test.instamojo.com

My motive is:
1) I have the required account on instamojo

2) Use the Merchant Signup API to create accounts for my child merchants on my marketplace.

3) Get access tokens for my child merchants.

4) Add their bank information.

5) Create payment links for my child merchants and share them with buyers, or redirect the buyers to these payment links to receive payments.

I am stuck on the 2nd step. 
I got my clientid and client_secret for C# but the 2nd step api showed following response:
{
"message": "You do not have permission to perform this action.", 
"success": false
}

Hence I tried with credentials of JAVA Wrapper, WHMCS, OpenCart 2.3.x, Cs-Cart

But still no success. can any one help me out.

Comment: Could you send the client id and client secret that you are using to support@instamojo.com ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to generate access token using the Application Based Authentication and use that access_token to SignUp new users. Please refer the doc here https://docs.instamojo.com/v2/docs/signup